# Get the code, the number and version into small columns

Tags: r, regex

I am new to R.

Currently I am working on the raw data. It includes thousands of code. I need to extract the code and number separately into small columns.

I have the data as below

```
df <- data.frame(num = 1:3, CD = c("1999HZ0BT", "1998HQ1ML", "1964MN3JK"))
```

Output I am wishing to have

```
df2 <- data.frame(num = 1:3, NUMBER = c(1999, 1998, 1964), VER = c(0,1,3), CD = c("HZBT", "HQML", "MNJK"))
```

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `substr`:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  mutate(NUMBER = substr(CD, 1, 4),
         VER = substr(CD, 7, 7),
         CD = paste(substr(CD, 5, 6), substr(CD, 8, 9), sep = ""))
```

```
  num   CD NUMBER VER
1   1 HZBT   1999   0
2   2 HQML   1998   1
3   3 MNJK   1964   3
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use regular expressions and `Map` to apply them consecutively.

```
res <- setNames(data.frame(df$num, 
                           Map(function(x, y) gsub(x, y, df$CD),
                               c("(\\d{4}).*", ".*\\w(\\d)\\w.*", "\\d"), 
                               c("\\1", "\\1", ""))),
                c("num", "NUMBER", "VER", "CD"))
res
#   num NUMBER VER   CD
# 1   1   1999   0 HZBT
# 2   2   1998   1 HQML
# 3   3   1964   3 MNJK
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `extract` from `tidyr` :

If you want to extract data based on position

```
library(tidyr)
df1 <- extract(df, CD, c('NUMBER', 'CD1', 'VER', 'CD2'), '(.{4})(..)(.)(..)')
```

Or if you want to extract data based on characters and numbers

```
df1 <- extract(df, CD, c('NUMBER', 'CD1', 'VER', 'CD2'), 
                  '(\\d+)([A-Z]+)(\\d+)([A-Z]+)')
```

Both of the above returns

```
df1
#  num NUMBER CD1 VER CD2
#1   1   1999  HZ   0  BT
#2   2   1998  HQ   1  ML
#3   3   1964  MN   3  JK
```

You can combine `CD1` and `CD2` using `unite`

```
unite(df1, CD, CD1, CD2, sep = "")

#  num NUMBER   CD VER
#1   1   1999 HZBT   0
#2   2   1998 HQML   1
#3   3   1964 MNJK   3
```

Comment: It is amazing! Thanks @Ronak Shah

Comment: I am curious about how to find based on position. Could you give me some resources to learn more about it? Thanks

Comment: Well, the `.` in my answer refer to each individual character in column `CD`. So it means first 4 characters is `NUMBER`, next 2 is `CD1`, next 1 character is `VER` and next 2 as `CD2`. This is a good site to learn about regular expressions https://www.regular-expressions.info/

Comment: It makes more sense to me now.